# Add html element between elements in sequence generated from range

Tags: php, html, arrays, range, sequence

Newb here trying to write a simple function which will generate a range of numbers (or letters) which is comma separated so that `genNumeric(1,10,3);` would return `1, 4, 7, 10` instead of `14710`

Code:

```
function genNumeric($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep){  
    foreach (range($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep) as $numSequence){          
        echo $numSequence;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop in this case, you can just use `implode()` outright:

```
function genNumeric($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep){
    echo implode(', ', range($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep));
}

genNumeric(1, 10, 3);
```

Or with the returned value:

```
function genNumeric($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep){
    return implode(', ', range($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep));
}

echo genNumeric(1, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer, it is super elegant and very simple and I never would have thought to use the 'implode' function.

Comment: @Chezshire sure no prob. im glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

Store the numbers you get back in an array and then implode the array however you want to have them separated.

```
function genNumeric($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep){
    $nums = array();
    foreach (range($numStart, $numEnd, $numStep) as $numSequence){          
        $nums[] = $numSequence;
    }
    echo implode(', ', $nums);
}
genNumeric(1, 10, 3);
```

Comment: This completely works, i opted for going with the other answer as it was more streamlined/economical in terms of characters and lines used to achieve the same result. But i want to say thank you as this was really nice to see a second method to achieve the same thing. Thank you very much.